# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in Yadcf select type

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am having a problem with select type in Yadcf. It does not allow brackets.
I have this code

```
{
   column_number: 9,
   filter_type: 'select',
   select_type: "select2",
   column_data_type: "html",
   html_data_type: "text",
   filter_match_mode: "exact",
   filter_default_label: "Select status",
},
```

HTML:

```
<td>Identified (In progress)</td>
```

So when page is loaded I have the error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Identified (In progress)
```

If I remove brackets select filter works fine and if I write

```
column_data_type: "text",
```

The error is gone but I can't filter by this value.

Comment: are you using legacy datatables or > 1.10? can you post your entire yadcf.init script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `column_data_type` to `html` only when the content of your `<td>` elements contains *html* code, for example `<td><span>Identified (In progress)</span></td>` and then yadcf will extract the *Identified (In progress)* from your `span`.

In you example the content of the `<td>` is a plain text, so you should declare the `column_data_type` at all because the [default value of `column_data_type` is text](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/beta/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L67) , b.t.w the default of the `[html_data_type` is *text*][2](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/beta/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L80) , so you shouldn't set its value too.

So just remove the

```
column_data_type: "html",
html_data_type: "text",
```

and it should work as expected

Here is [a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xk4oqz8s/8/) (using latest beta version)

```
yadcf.init(oTable, [{
    column_number: 0,
    select_type: "select2",
    select_type_options: {
        width: '200px'       
    },       
    filter_match_mode: "exact"
}]);
```

---

p.s I'm the author of [yadcf plugin](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, but it is very strange I removed the code you pointed me to remove but when I select Identified (In progress) it shows Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries. I see that the code is working in your jsfiddle but the same code is not working with my tables. I tried using yadcf.init with .DataTable() but still shows 0 records.

Comment: @KirillRyzhkov, you need to use the [latest yadcf JS file](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/tree/master/beta) for this to work.

Comment: yep , you have to use the latest beta version for the exact to work with brackets or any other regex alike char

Comment: Thanks, I was using 0.8.8.beta.26

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf).

Try to use `filter_match_mode: "contains"` and `column_data_type: "text"`, as shown below:

```
{
   column_number: 9,
   filter_type: 'select',
   select_type: "select2",
   column_data_type: "text",
   filter_match_mode: "contains",
   filter_default_label: "Select status"
},
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xk4oqz8s/) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need exact match mode.

Comment: `exact` didn't work until @Daniel (author of [yadcf plugin](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/)) added a fix addressing the problem, see [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30231106/3549014).

Comment: yep , you have to use the latest beta version for the exact to work with brackets